# Instance of Show Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am doing my homework and I have a problem doing an instance of Show and I can't solve it, I tried a lot of things. I copy you the error and my code below.

My code:

```
type Height = Float
type Width = Float
type Radius = Float
data Rectangle = Rectangle Height Width
data Circle = Circle Radius

class Shape a where
    area :: a -> Float
    perimeter :: a -> Float

instance Shape Rectangle where
    area (Rectangle h w) = h * w
    perimeter (Rectangle b a) = (2*b) + (2*a) 

instance Shape Circle where
    area (Circle r) = pi * r**2
    perimeter (Circle r) = 2*r*pi

type Volume = Float

volumePrism :: (Shape a) => a -> Height -> Volume
volumePrism base height = (area base) * height


surfacePrism ancho largo alto = (2*ancho*largo) + (2*largo*alto) + (2*ancho*alto)


instance Show a =>  Show (Shape a) where 
    show (Rectangle h w) = "Rectángulo de base " ++ w ++ "y altura " ++ h
```

And what the error says:

```
The first argument of 'Show' should have kind '*'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Shape` is a typeclass, and you can’t make a typeclass an instance of another typeclass. (You can make all types that are an instance of a typeclass an instance of a different typeclass as well, but that doesn’t appear to be what you’re trying to do here.)

Rather, you appear to want to implement `Show` on `Rectangle`. So say that explicitly:

```
instance Show Rectangle where 
    show (Rectangle h w) = "Rectángulo de base " ++ w ++ "y altura " ++ h
```

Answer (score 9):

What you want to do is not possible.  `Shape` is a typeclass, not a data type, so it has no constructors you can pattern match on.  You could do something like

```
instance (Shape a) => Show a where
    show shape = "Area: " ++ show (area shape) ++ " Perimeter: " ++ show (perimeter shape)
```

But this does not seem to be what you want.  Instead, you should just define `Show` for each type individually:

```
instance Show Rectangle where
    show (Rectangle h w) = "Rectangle with base " ++ show w ++ " and height " ++ show h

instance Show Circle where
    show (Circle r) = "Circle with radius " ++ show r
```

The error about the "kind" can be quite cryptic for beginners (and sometimes experienced haskellers!), but in this case it's fairly straightforward.  This does involve a new concept, though.  In Haskell, you have values which have a type, such as functions, constants, even monadic actions.  You can also talk about the "type of a type", what is known as the *kind*.  There are a couple that you should know about and be comfortable using: `*` and `Constraint`.  Most types you'll see only involve `*` and arrows between them.  All "fully applied" data types should have kind `*`, it basically just means that it doesn't take any type parameters, so

```
> :kind Int
Int :: *
> :kind String
String :: *
> :kind IO ()
IO () :: *
> :kind Maybe Int
Maybe Int :: *
> :kind Either String Int
Either String Int :: *
```

However, you can have *higher-kinded* types as well:

```
> :kind IO    -- Note lack of ()
IO :: * -> *
> :kind Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
> :kind Either
Either :: * -> * -> *
```

Each `*` just represents another *fully applied type*.  That last detail is important, it means you can't have `Either IO Maybe`, because that would be a nonsensical type.  These can be higher order as well:

```
> import Control.Monad.State
> :kind StateT
StateT :: * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *
```

It's the same syntax as with function types, just without kind variables.

The other one you really need to know about is `Constraint`.  This one is specially for typeclasses:

```
> :kind Show
Show :: * -> Constraint
> :kind Num
Num :: * -> Constraint
> :kind MonadState
MonadState :: * -> (* -> *) -> Constraint
```

And when fully applied they return a typeclass, rather than a datatype.

In case you're curious, there are GHC extensions that let you work with more complicated kinds, even allowing you to specify the kinds for a type or typeclass.  There are some interesting tricks you can do with it, but these are generally considered more advanced features of the type system.

Comment: To amplify bheklilr's laconic "this does not seem to be what you want": You *definitely do not want* the first instance here, `instance (Shape a) => Show a where ...`. It may look seductively close to what you want, but Haskell Doesn't Work Like That.

Answer (score 2):

Your instance declaration is not meaningful. Translated to English it would read as something like "for every `a` that is an instance of `Show`, `a` being an instance of `Shape` is an instance of `Show`" or something incomprehensible like that.

Just make `Rectangle` and `Circle` instances of `Show` and leave `Shape` out of it, unless you want to require that every instance of `Shape` must be an instance of `Show`, which is something that you need to put into the declaration of `Shape`.